# Keycloak most basic installation giving 401 Status Code on AKS

Tags: keycloak, azure-aks

Installing keycloak on minikube works fine after following https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started/getting-started-kube.

But when I try on Azure Kubernetes Service;   I am getting following response on browser for URL https://keycloak.10.18.80.36.nip.io/ OR https://keycloak.10.18.80.36.nip.io/admin

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    
  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "Unauthorized",
  "reason": "Unauthorized",
  "code": 401
}
```

I am not even getting screen to put in username and password. Help is appreciated. Also, when I was accessing from browser it was giving SSL error; so I proceed with *Not secure*. I am using IP of AKS "API server address"

Comment: Is your ingress addon enabled?

Comment: I am NOT using minikube but using kubernetes ; so no need of add-on. also, if ingress was not enabled I guess I wont even get response.

Comment: what are you getting for https://keycloak.10.18.80.36.nip.io/auth ?

Comment: @Abhijeet same json response. even for this URL

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to solve it to great extent.

Use helm chart. Good part of using helm charts is that it also creates postgres which takes care of persistence layer. Otherwise whenever pod is deleted all users will go away.

1. helm repo add azure-marketplace https://marketplace.azurecr.io/helm/v1/repo
2. helm install keycloak-helm azure-marketplace/keycloak
3. Now check the Service ( Load Balancer ) external IP and use it to access on browser. This was the key part. as we don't have minikube so we cannot use `$ minikube ip`
4. On browser you can login using following credentials:

Username: user

echo Password: $(kubectl get secret --namespace default keycloak-helm -o jsonpath="{.data.admin-password}" | base64 --decode)
apHc7vK5vL